# Is it possible to video record the screen using MediaRecorder using javascript?

Tags: javascript, video, screen-capture

I would like to capture either part or the whole screen and record it as a video from a web page in javascript.

Currently, I can record video from a web cam with the built in MediaRecorder but I would like to know if it is possible to get screen output and use that as a stream for the MediaRecorder?

I'd like to know if there is a standard way to do this without using any 3rd party libraries? (I can record audio/web cam video in almost all the browsers as of 2018)

Answer (score 0):

You can record Screen or Windows only using browser extensions (in Chrome for instance with [these](https://github.com/muaz-khan/WebRTC-Experiment/tree/master/Chrome-Extensions)). Which [as you can see](https://github.com/muaz-khan/Chrome-Extensions/blob/master/desktopCapture/manifest.json) they ask specific permissions to the browser.

Alternatively you can record content inside your web app using MediaRecorder. But unfortunately has a pretty [limited support](https://caniuse.com/#feat=mediarecorder).

As you pointed out, stream from webcam is [widely supported](https://caniuse.com/#feat=stream) today.